# Fedora 25 - refusing to recognize Java JDK, $JAVA_HOME appears to be correct

Tags: java, compilation, bazel, fedora-25

I am on a server  with Fedora 25 installed.  I am trying to compile bazel, and each time I try, it gives me this same message:

```
[~]$bash bz/./compile.sh
```

INFO: You can skip this first step by providing a path to the bazel binary as second argument:
INFO:    `bz/./compile.sh compile /path/to/bazel`
  Building Bazel from scratch

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME (jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131) is not a path to a working JDK.
```

But I can list the jdk files!

```
[~]$ls jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131  
bin        javafx-src.zip  man          THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
COPYRIGHT  jre             README.html  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
db         lib             release
include    LICENSE         src.zip
```

And the bin directory!

```
[~]$ls jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131/bin  
appletviewer  javafxpackager  jdb      jrunscript    pack200      unpack200
ControlPanel  javah           jdeps    jsadebugd     policytool   wsgen
extcheck      javap           jhat     jstack        rmic         wsimport
idlj          javapackager    jinfo    jstat         rmid         xjc
jar           java-rmi.cgi    jjs      jstatd        rmiregistry
jarsigner     javaws          jmap     jvisualvm     schemagen
java          jcmd            jmc      keytool       serialver
javac         jconsole        jmc.ini  native2ascii  servertool
javadoc       jcontrol        jps      orbd          tnameserv  



[~]$echo $JAVA_HOME    
jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131
```

So I have no idea how to proceed. It just refuses to recognize the jdk, even though I can see it where it should be. ???

The reason I am doing this is because I need to compile Tensorflow, so I can run all 16 processors on the server.

Comment: You need to use an *absolute* path.  "jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131" is relative

Comment: I'm assuming you mean setting JAVA_HOME=/jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131       That did not change anything.   The message does not change other than there is now the "/" in front of the path that it lists.  echo $java_home does the same.   I extracted the Java package directly into the home directory, so the path starts with jdk-8u131-linux-x64.   Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I moved the bazel files, all of them to the home directory, where I knew javac and java were both working.   I then tried again to compile, and got the same error.

Comment: Well "/jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_13" is almost certainly the wrong path on a Fedora system.  You need to use the >>right<< absolute path.  Obviously.

Comment: The right path will depend on how you installed Java.  If you don't know where you installed it use the `find` utility to find it.  (See `man find` for details.)

Comment: I created  a java file, compiled it, and ran it in home directory, so the path appears to be correct, that would not work otherwise.  Yet when I try  to use the  command bash ./compile.sh, I get the same old error.   That appears to tell me that the  path is correct.  I used the  find function originally to find java and javac.   The java file I created  was just a small hello world, but it compiled and ran perfectly.  It seems like it has something to do with what the compile.sh file is trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't prove anything.  The `java` and `javac` commands do not use `$JAVA_HOME`, and the shell doesn't use `$JAVA_HOME` to find the commands.  It finds them using `$PATH`.  Unless you actually have created the "jdk-8u131-linux-x64" directory in your system's root directory, that path is wrong.  (And if you did do that, why?  That is a bad idea.)

Comment: I guess this begs the question, how exactly should I install java?   Last time I just extracted to the Home directory.   I am going to wipe the disk, re-install Fedora 25 because I need to work off of a clean install, get Java running, then I will at least know that everything else is good.

Comment: Found this link, which appears to give good directions on installing the JDK on fedora 25, proceeding. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/JDK_on_Fedora  Thanks again for the help, btw.

Comment: I have tensorflow installed, I have not determined yet if it is using all processors yet.

Comment: Tensorflow is NOT running on all processors, however, I have managed to get everything set up.  It appears I will need to uninstall Tensorflow, then compile it.  (Ideally, I should have not installed Tensorflow at all, and went for compiling it once I had everything else ready.)  Many dependencies, likely due to the fact that this is cutting edge.   The reason that bazel was not working properly was because Java was not installed properly.   You cannot just unzip it to a directory, you have to find the install directions for it and follow them closely.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem. One has to install Java-devel via `sudo dnf install java-devel`, do `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64` (depends of course on the actual version) and run `./compile.sh` from the bazel files in the same terminal. Further I recommend to add $JAVA_HOME permanently to $PATH via `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH`.